# Django - AllAuth How to style the email.html template?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-allauth

Quick question.

I'm beefing up the authentication for my Django application. I would like to have users change and verify their emails with Allauth but I can't figure out how to style a template.

Is there a way how we can style the `email.html` template?

I tried to add `{{ form.as_p }}` but I only get an email field.
I don't know how to add everything else.

I tried looking at the Github for allauth as well for the `email.html` page and I don't understand it because there's a bunch of template code. I don't know what to strip out or keep.

Below is what the page looks like without styling.

Any help is gladly appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an older version of the allauth repo that had templates that I understood a lot better.

https://github.com/HackerEarth/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/email.html

Now I have it working. If anyone has any suggestions I'm open to hearing them.

Thanks!